# Calling objective-C typedef block from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to call a method from swift.
The method is in a singleton written in objective-C

the block in the header file:

```
typedef void(^VPersonResultBlock)(Person *person, NSError *error);

- (void)askForMe:(VPersonResultBlock)block;
```

and here's the implementation of that method.

```
- (void)askForMe:(VPersonResultBlock)block
{
if (_me) block(_me,nil);
else {
    [Person getMeWithBlock:^(PFObject *person, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _me = (Person *)person;
            block(_me,nil);
        }

        else if (error) {
            block(nil,error);
        }
        else {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{
                                       NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Operation was unsuccessful.", nil),
                                       NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"The operation failed to retrieve the user.", nil),
                                       NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Check your network connection and try again", nil)
                                       };
            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"VisesAsyncErrorDomain" code:-10 userInfo:userInfo];
            block(nil,error);
        }
    }];
}
}
```

In Objective-C, I can call this and it autocompletes without confusion.

```
[[VDataStore instance] askForMe:^(Person *person, NSError *error) {
    // do things with myself that aren't strange
}];
```

Now let's say I want to call the same method from swift. The bridging header is setup, with the  header file imported, but swift's expectation is confusing.

```
VDataStore.askForMe(VDataStore)
```

This is what shows up in the autocomplete options

```
(VPersonResultBlock!) -> Void askForMe(self: VDataStore)
```

what I was hoping for, was for this to autocomplete into a closure, and although it appears to see all of the information correctly, what it's expecting isn't lining up with what objective-C seems to understand.

How do I call this properly from swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly translate your ObjC calling code to Swift is

```
VDataStore.instance().askForMe() {
    person, error in 
    // do things with myself that aren't strange
}
```

Your problem is that `askForMe` is instance method but you are accessing from class object `VDataStore.askForMe`. Swift will give you a function object that takes an instance as input.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, that solved it; thank you.